# Stop users from listening to my deep link

Tags: android, flutter, android-intent, deep-linking, firebase-dynamic-links

I have a firebase dynamic link. My app is configured to listen to my deep link intents.

```
<intent-filter android:autoVerify="true">
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.VIEW" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            <category android:name="android.intent.category.BROWSABLE" />

            <data
                android:host="www.example.com"
                android:path="/en"
                android:scheme="https" />
        </intent-filter>
```

I'm worried someone may use this intent filter in their own app and listen to my deep link intents.
He may then extract any valuable info appended to my deep link (**[www.example.com/valubleInfo=someCode](http://www.example.com/valubleInfo=someCode)**) so I want to verify that only my app is able to extract that valuable info.